# Python pywinauto Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

Tags: python, tkinter, pywinauto

Python 3.7.1 // 
Tk version 8.6 // 
pywinauto-0.6.8 // 
PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1 x64

The objective is to have the button send keys to the window in the background.
Issue appears due to the presence of pywinauto.
If inactive:

```
from tkinter import *
# from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

def left_click(event):
    # send_keys('%{TAB}')
    # send_keys('{{}ENTER{}}')
    print("hello")

root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text="Other")
label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
bt1_label1 = Button(root, text="Button_1", bg="red")
bt1_label1.grid(row=0, column=1)
bt1_label1.bind("<Button-1>", left_click)

root.mainloop()
```

Return when manually closing the tkinter window is:

```
hello

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If pywinauto is active (uncommented):

```
from tkinter import *
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

def left_click(event):
    # send_keys('%{TAB}')
    # send_keys('{{}ENTER{}}')
    print("hello")

root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text="Other")
label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
bt1_label1 = Button(root, text="Button_1", bg="red")
bt1_label1.grid(row=0, column=1)
bt1_label1.bind("<Button-1>", left_click)

root.mainloop()
```

Return when manually closing the tkinter window is:

```
hello

Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Try to reverse the`import` order.

Comment: Reversing the import order did not work. As it stands in that code, `pywinauto` isn't even used when it's uncommented, but that is enough to change the return code somehow.

Comment: Relevant [pywinauto/issues/894](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/894)

Comment: Can you try to uninstall `comtypes` and try again with `import pywinauto`?

Comment: It doesn't work at all without `comtypes`.
At this point, I suspect it's an incompatibility between the Python version and Pywinauto.

Comment: Can any of you actually run my second code without the error? If so, please let me know on what versions, so I can try to duplicate.